# SwingWorker Possible Bug

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, jlabel, swingworker

While using `SwingWorker` to sequentially update my front end, I think I may have found a bug.

I have create a server which listen for connections. A connection might only initiate in a few minutes, so I created a little connecting animation that plays while the server is waiting for a new incoming connection.

A `SwingWorker<T,T>` is used to update a `JLabel` every 0.5 seconds with a character, which in the end, creates a character that bounces from one end of the panel to next, upon connection, the animation is removed and the `JLabel` is updated with different text.

This has been working all fine and dandy, but I have recently realised that the animation sometimes freezes, but yet, every time I ran the animation, it stopped and the `JLabel` updated correctly.

**I then realised that the `JLabel` text does not update when I am on a different workspace.**
*(Edit: Where workspace refers to the ability to switch between desktops (workspaces) in Linux (I'm on Linux Mint 15). See: http://linux.about.com/library/gnome/blgnome2n4a.htm*

I tested and retested:

**Test A:**

1. Start listening for connections
2. Application Animation starts (powered by `SwingWorker`)
3. Keep app open on current workspace
4. Client connects and animation correctly disappears
5. `Jlabel` correctly updates to new text.

**Test B:**

1. Start listening for connections
2. Animation starts (powered by `SwingWorker`)
3. Move to a different workspace by pressing `Ctrl+Alt, (arrow key)` and leave app on previous workspace.
4. Wait until client connects and move back to workspace containing app.
5. `Jlabel` froze and DID NOT update to new text.
6. ***This is where it gets weird:*** If I select a `JMenuItem`, which will in turn overlap with the animation, the overlapping part of the text will then UPDATE partially to the correct text.

I have not tested this on another Linux distribution, but will do so after I get feedback that my code is not the cause of this problem.

CODE:

ConnectingAnimation will be running all the time, but only updating the animation when the server is not connected.

```
public class ConnectingAnimation extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (true) {
            while (!connected) {
                try {
                    ...
                    //Append text to StringBuilder
                    ...
                    //publish updated text to be displayed next
                    publish(sb.toString());
                    //Sleep
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            //Waits until clientConnected() is called
            try {
                synchronized (clientConnection) {
                    clientConnected.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.logException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(final List<String> chunks) {
        for (final String update : chunks) {
            if (connected) {
                connectionStatusLabel.setText("Client Connected");
                break;
            }
            connectionStatusLabel.setText(update);
        }
    }
}
```

clientConnected() will be called by an external module notifying the animation to stop

```
public static void clientConnected() {
    ...
    synchronized (clientConnection) {
        connected = true;
        clientConnection.notify();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "workspace"?

Comment: I would say a workspace is the directory or directories that store your "source" files, or all your files, because they might be more than just source code.

Comment: When do you update your `connected` variable? It should happen within one of the `synchronized(clientConnection)` blocks but I don’t see it within neither…

Comment: "workspace" refers to desktop workspace in Linux, as in, use Ctrl+Alt and (Arrow Key) to switch to a different desktop or workspace.

Comment: @Holger connected variable has been moved to the clientConnect() method for continuity

Comment: Just note that this is very unlikely to be related to swingworker. It's probably the particular window manager or X server that does not propagate update or paint events to the application when moving between workspace. Check if this is the case by running another desktop environment or window manager. Also print some text to the console in the doInBackground() and process() to verify if it's called at all, or if the entire event system gets suspended. Might be interresting to see if a `connectionStatusLabel.repaint()` after you change its text can work around it.

Comment: @nos I added added `System.out.println` to doInBackground() and process(), and I can verify that it is being called successfully in case A and B. Repaint had no effect. I can now confirm that once you move to a different workspace, the JLabel remains in the exact same state as it was left, no changes occur, even when connectionStatusLabel.repaint() or connectionStatusLabel.setText() is used to update the text. I have yet to test on another desktop environment, I have a feeling it is the cause.